# Visitor pattern. Is void* an acceptable return type for a completely abstract interface?

Tags: c++, theory

I have an AST, represented in the usual way (a tree of nodes of an abstract type). I have several uses cases for traversing this tree (an optimizer, which returns another AST; IR code generation, which returns a `llvm::Value*`; and a debug analyzer, which simply outputs to stdout and returns nothing).

A visitor feels like the right way to go here, but the differing return types through each use case of the visitor make it hard to see how to implement an interface for this. I considered this:

```
class Visitor;

class ASTNode {
public:
  virtual void accept(Visitor *visitor);
};

class Visitor {
public:
  virtual void visit(CallNode *node) = 0;
  virtual void visit(BinExprNode *node) = 0;
  // etc
};
```

Because of the lack of return value, each Visitor implementation would need to build up internal state and provide a `result()` method with a suitable return type. That is complex, however, since each call to `visit()` needs some context around the expression being visited (i.e. the call standing alone, or is it being used as part of a binary expression?). It makes it tricky for things like binary expression code generation to collect return values from visiting the nodes of the operands (I could do it with an internal temporary state variable or some such, but it feels over-engineered) and hard to reason about (the state keeps changing).

```
class OptimizingVisitor : public Visitor {
  ASTNode *m_result;
public:
  ASTNode *result() {
    return m_result;
  }

  void setResult(ASTNode *node) {
    m_result = node;
  }

  void visit(CallNode *node) {
    node->left()->accept(this);
    ASTNode *optimizedL = result();
    node->right()->accept(this);
    ASTNode *optimizedR = result();
    setResult(new CallNode(optimizedL, optimizedR));
  }

  // ... snip ...
};
```

I could make it even more complex to avoid the "state keeps changing" issue by passing in a new visitor for each node. It just feels like this problem warrants a more functional solution.

Really, I'd like to write the above much more simply and easier to read:

```
class OptimizingVisitor : public Visitor {
public:
  ASTNode* visit(CallNode *node) {
    ASTNode *optimizedL = node->left()->accept(this);
    ASTNode *optimizedR = node->right()->accept(this);
    return new CallNode(optimizedL, optimizedR);
  }

  // ... snip ...
};
```

Of course now I've changed the return type, so it doesn't fit my Visitor contract. Far from defining completely separate interfaces for each possible implementation of a a Visitor and making the AST aware of those visitor types, it seems the only really logical thing to use is a `void*`. Does this sort of API warrant the use of `void*`? Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Could you us a template?

Comment: I'm not sure. For the Visitor part, yes. But the AST also needs to comply in it's `accept()` method. Could you post a (short) example?

Comment: Good idea BTW. This shows my lack of experience with C++ :)

Comment: Visitor feels wrong to me. The point of walking the tree is to decorate it with additional information for later use such as optimisation and code generation.

Comment: No, I am not *changing* the tree, I want to just "look at it". I generally try to avoid mutable interface where they are not strictly needed. Subjective, I know.

Comment: @NeilKirk could you post the template suggestion as an answer? No code example needed, I can already see that it will work.

Comment: Generally, using `void*` (or `object` in Java/C#) is just a reminder that you really wanted generic programming techniques. But I think in this case, you need return type covariance on `accept` rather than generics, and have each `visit` method return the same type that it takes as argument.

Comment: I can't do something like this? https://gist.github.com/d11wtq/9575063

Answer (score 4):

If I get this right, I might have something useful. Referring to your sample at https://gist.github.com/d11wtq/9575063, you cannot have

```
class ASTNode {
public:
   template <class T>
   virtual T accept(Visitor<T> *visitor);
};
```

because there are no template virtual functions. However, you may have a generic class

```
template <class D, class T>
struct host {
   virtual T accept(Visitor<T> * visitor);
   // I guess, { return visitor->visit(static_cast <D*>(this)); }
};
```

and a collection

```
template <class D, class... T>
struct hosts : host <D, T>... { };
```

so that, when the set of possible return types is limited, you can say e.g.

```
class ASTNode : public hosts <ASTNode, T1, T2, T3> {
public:
   // ...
};
```

Now you have three different Visitor contracts of return types `T1,T2,T3`.

Comment: Hey, sorry for the delay in replying—I had to go out for the day. As a C++ newbie, this looks like a syntax jungle :) Why do you use a struct instead of a class? I'll have a play around with this and see how it feels. I'm leaning more towards keeping it simple and just using void* (or object) for now though.

Comment: I finished up with the `setResult()` and `result()` option, but wrapped it behind a facade to hide that implementation. It feels like all the options are ugly. Dynamic typing gets a +1 in cases like this.

Comment: It's funny that of all syntax here, using `struct` was your greatest difficulty :-) Anyhow, remember that `struct` and `class` are the same thing except that `struct` has `public` inheritance and `public` members by default, whereas `class` has `private` by default. You can even declare something as a `struct` and then define or specialize it as a `class` later on. So what you choose for each case is just a matter of convenience.

Comment: @d11wtq Advice: `void*` is primarily for low-level serializing like allocating memory or file i/o. Otherwise, keep it as a last resort when everything else fails. What looks simple now *will* become a nightmare later on, for you or (worse) for someone else. Find out what is the pattern of your return type. If there's just a limited set of possible types, my solution applies easily. If you have a *minimal* working sample with 2-3 different return types, I'll be happy to convert it for you.

Comment: @d11wtq (cont'd) If the return type is just the same as the input type, follow dialer's solution. If it's a function (*type* function) of the input, I think this solution could also be adjusted. If there are dozens of visitors with arbitrary return types following no particular pattern and dozens of distinct return types, then I'm afraid you're in trouble.

Comment: @iavr I'm having exactly the same problem, considering the templated base  solution you suggested. However, if I make ASTNode base a template, I no longer have runtime polymorphism, ie, I can't have the same ASTNode* object saved in a container and evaluate them with the same calling code.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this is helpful.

Using return type covariance to make `accept()` calls type-safe:

```
class Visitor;

class ASTNode
{
public:
    virtual ASTNode* accept(Visitor* visitor);
};

class CallNode;
class BinaryExpressionNode;

class Visitor
{
public:
    virtual CallNode* visit(CallNode* node) = 0;
    virtual BinaryExpressionNode* visit(BinaryExpressionNode* node) = 0;
};
```

Implementations:

```
class CallNode : public ASTNode
{
public:
    CallNode(BinaryExpressionNode* left, BinaryExpressionNode* right);

    // return type covariance
    CallNode* accept(Visitor* visitor) override
    {
        return visitor->visit(this);
    }

    BinaryExpressionNode* left();
    BinaryExpressionNode* right();
};

class BinaryExpressionNode : public ASTNode
{
public:
    BinaryExpressionNode* accept(Visitor* visitor) override
    {
        return visitor->visit(this);
    }
}

class OptimizingVisitor : public Visitor
{
public:
    CallNode* visit(CallNode* node) override
    {
        // return type covariance will make this operation type-safe:
        BinaryExpressionNode* left = node->left()->accept(this);
        auto right = node->right()->accept(this);
        return new CallNode(left, right);
    }

    BinaryExpressionNode* visit(BinaryExpressionNode* node) override
    {
        return new BinaryExpressionNode(node);
    }
};
```

Comment: Nice! Assuming of course that covariance is what is needed by the application.

Comment: Hey, thanks heaps. This is very nice, though it only supports returning types of `ASTNode*` (or derivates thereof). I'm also passing in a visitor that generates `llvm::Value*` objects, which come from an entirely different ancestry.

Comment: @d11wtq I've put a lot of thought into this since you've asked the question, and I had also tried to solve this very problem (converting between *arbitrary* polymorphic object graphs in a 100% type-safe manner) before, but with little success. It boils down to either having a visitor with as many generic type arguments as there are `visit` methods, or returning `void*` (whose C# equivalent `object` is used in other code bases, for example the SharpDevelop AST). Though I'm not done thinking and might edit this answer later with some more in-depth analysis.