# Implementing Visitor Pattern in Java whit two different return types

Tags: java, visitor-pattern

I am trying to implement the Visitor Pattern in java (exercise for home, sorry) for an object structure which has methods with different return types (int and void).

A concreteVisitor (i.e., **CostAss**) returns *int* and a second ConcreteVisitor (i.e., **drawCosts**) returns *void* (i.e., a print of the cost).

[image]

I have the problem to understand how to implement this problem. I am not allowed to create two accept methods (one int e one void) in the interface Employee

[image]

Comment: Where did that flow chart come from?  You can't have two different return types for the same method unless you change the parameters.

Comment: Thanks! this is my problem. I don't understant how to manage this situation. In one ConcreteVisitor I need to return int. In the second ConcreteVisitor I need to print the value.

Comment: if you can resolve this problem with Java. Generics

Comment: @vincenzopalazzo I am not allowed to use generics in this exercise (teacher mentality)

Comment: @GianniSpear Try to explain to your teacher that the diagram they shared isn't completely suitable for the language you've (I guess, voluntarily) chosen. Pick up another diagram from the Internet (e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern#Java_example), and implement it. You both would benefit from it.

Comment: similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29593091/visitor-design-pattern-return-type https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10164714/implementing-visitor-pattern-while-allowing-different-return-types-of-functions https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22430211/visitor-pattern-is-void-an-acceptable-return-type-for-a-completely-abstract-in

Answer (score 6):

From a Java perspective, these methods are the same because the return type is not a part of the method signature.

The diagram wasn't intended for Java. However, it's possible to work around it with generics.

```
interface Employee<T> {
  Optional<T> accept(Visitor visitor);
}

class Assistant implements Employee<Integer> {
  @Override
  public Optional<Integer> accept(Visitor visitor) {
    return Optional.of(100);
  }
}

class Manager implements Employee<Void> {
  @Override
  public Optional<Void> accept(Visitor visitor) {
    return Optional.empty();
  }
}
```

I am not a huge supporter of this idea, I just wanted to share the way it *can* be done.

Comment: Do you know of an alternative way that you might be inclined to hugely support?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a method accept with the void type return and the two concrete visitors have a state, an example

```
public interface IVisitor {

    void visit(Employee employee);

    int getStatus();
}

public class VisitPrint implement IVisitor{

    public void visit(Employee employee){
      //todo
    }    

    public int getStatus(){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Not supported operation");
    }
}

public class VisitSum implement IVisitor{

    int status;

    public void visit(Employee employee){
      //todo
    }

    public int getStatus(){
        return status;
    }
}

public interface Employee {
  void accept(Visitor visitor);
}
```

This solution resolves the problem and respect the teacher mentality.

Comment: ```public void getStatus(){
        return status;
    }``` doesn't work

Comment: If you compiled it, you would see... `implement` and from a `void` method, an `int` is returned

Comment: @AndrewTobilko absolutely yes, thanks so much, I have committed the distraction error. I thought the visitor with the state was the error